# Django pagination for api response objects

Tags: python, django

I am building a blogsite and I am using a cryptonews api to display the news on the page. I want to display 10 api objects per page. When I tried it as shown below I get an error.

from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    import requests
    import json

```
# Grab crypto Price Data
price_request = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,EOS,LTC,XRP,BCH,XEC,BNB,BGG,TRX&tsyms=USD")
price = json.loads(price_request.content)

# Grab Crypto News
api_request = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN")
api = json.loads(api_request.content)
paginator = Paginator(api, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')

items = paginator.page(page)

return render(request, 'home.html', {'items': items, 'price': price})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Paginator function takes a list but the response from "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN" is a dict that is why it crashes. I think you can extract the data you need from the dict then reconstruct a list with the results you need and pass it to the Paginator.

For further info, you can refer to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/)